# Django - How to use the results of a Django view query as an input to a different Django view query

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am new to coding / Django and apologize in advance if this question has been asked before.  I have searched StackOverflow and haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for.

I am building a Django application that allows a user to search for a property record via a unique identifier (referred to as APN in my Django model).  In addition, the application is designed to deliver consumer population data for the state in which a given property is located (e.g. California, Florida, etc.)

When a user submits their APN search query, the application generates a page that displays the Address, City, and State.  The state field is meant to be linked to a separate page that displays the state-level population data described above.  For example, if the State for a given property is "Colorado", the user should be directed to a page that displays population data for Colorado (as opposed to a different state) when they click the link.

Here are my models:

```
class AnnualPopulation(models.Model):
    State = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    Population_2022 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Population_2023 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class PropDots2(models.Model):
    APN = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
```

Here is my form:

```
class PropSearchForm2(forms.Form):
    APN = forms.CharField(required=True, label='APN')
```

Here are my views:

```
#search for a property record by APN

class PropDetailSearch(FormView):
    template_name = 'search/propdetailsearch2.html'
    form_class = PropSearchForm2
    success_url = 'search/propdetailview2.html'

#return Address, City, and State for a given property record and display on new page

class PropDetailView2(ListView):
    model = PropDots2
    template_name = 'search/propdetail2.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('APN')
        object_list = PropDots2.objects.filter(APN__icontains=query)
        return object_list

#return population data for queried State and display on new page

class StatePopulationView(ListView):
    model = AnnualPopulation
    template_name = 'search/populationresult.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        querystate = self.request.GET.get('State')
        object_list = AnnualPopulation.objects.filter(Q(State__icontains=querystate))

        return object_list
```

Here are my templates:

```
# form to search for property record by APN:

{% block content %}

<h1>Enter Search Criteria</h1>


<form action="{% url 'propdetail2' %}" method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
  <input class="btn btn-primary" name="q" type="submit" placeholder="Search">
</form>

{% endblock content %}

# page that displays Address, City, and State for property record that user searches for:

{% block content %}

{% for PropDots2 in object_list %}

    <h2><a href="{% url 'populationresult' PropDots2.State %}">{{ PropDots2.Address }} {{ PropDots2.City }}</a></h2>

{% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}

# page that displays population data for a given property's state:

{% block content %}

{% for AnnualPopulation in object_list %}

<h4>{{ AnnualPopulation.Population_2022 }}  {{ AnnualPopulation.Population_2023 }}</h4>

{% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

And here are my URL patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('populationresult/<str:State>/', StatePopulationView.as_view(), name='populationresult'),
    path('propdetailsearch2/', PropDetailSearch.as_view(), name='propdetailsearch2'),
    path('propdetail2/', PropDetailView2.as_view(), name='propdetail2'),
```

All of the functionality I'm trying to build works with the exception of the state population page.

When I click on the "State" link for a give property, the application generates a new URL that correctly specifies the state for which the population data should be returned (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/populationresult/CA/).  However, instead of generating the new page that displays the population data, the application generates the following error message:

ValueError at /populationresult/CA/
Cannot use None as a query value

So it is clear that the state value isn't actually being passed through to my StatePopulationView view.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.  And once again, I apologize if this question has already been answered somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but there are differences between request.GET.get("state") and URL parameters in Django. The first is displayed in the URL as `?state=CA` while the latter is like this `populationresult/CA/`.

In class based views you can access URL parameters using the kwargs.
`querystate = self.kwargs.get("State")`

Also a minor note, I'd create a State model and have a foreign key for both AnnualPopulation and PopDots2, it'll make your life easier if you want to get the state more often.

Comment: Thank you very much, user20223018.  I changed my StatePopulation views you suggested and it worked like a charm.

I'm sure this is an ignorant question, but would you mind elaborating on the foreign key and how that would impact the approach I've taken here? 

Also, if I were to use a function based view instead of a class based view, could I still access the URL parameters using the kwargs?

Comment: No worries for the questions, for the function based view it would look like this: `def state_population(request, state): xxxx`. Foreign keys make it easy to link different objects/models together by using the primary key to link them together. Right now, let's say you change the way you identify states from CA -> California, you'd have to update the reference for that for all objects you have. Take a look at this documentation for some more elaborate explanation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks again for your help, user20223018.  I greatly appreciate it.